# OleControl instantiated to wrong type - only when using in Reg Free COM?

Tags: vb6, activex, visual-foxpro, foxpro, regfreecom

I have an ActiveX control (created using C#) that I am adding to a form in Visual FoxPro using late binding. It works without problems when I register the control.

I want to use reg free COM and created necessary manifest files. Now it load and displays in an inactive state until I double click or grammatically activate it. I don't think it has anything to do with the reg free com manifest files. However is there something I need to do to set it up before/after making the late binding call `AddObject()`?

```
this.AddObject('OleControl1', 'oleControl', 'SomeCompany.SomeOleControl')
```

When I check the `OleTypeAllowed` Property of the OleControl created by `AddObject()` it is `1` (Embedded OLE object) instead of `-2` (ActiveX object). So the OleControl got instantiated to the wrong type.

I also tried the following:

1. `DEFINE` a subclass of `OleControl` and set the property `OleTypeAllowed = -2`. Used late binding to load the control. It did not work as required. The `OleTypeAllowed` came back as `1`
2. Registered the ActiveX control. Added the ActiveX control to the project as a subclass using the visual editor. Unregistered the control. Used late binding to load the control. It did not work as required. The `OleTypeAllowed` came back as `1`.

Is it possible to load the OleControl as a ActiveX control?

Any input from VB that I can convert to FoxPro would also be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add the manifest files you are using for Reg-Free COM?

Comment: Has anyone ever found a solution to this? FoxPro just refuses to load a .NET ActiveX control as an OLEControl. It's always treated as an OLEBoundControl.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the `miscStatusContent` attribute wrong. This a snippet from a VB6 app manifest we deploy:

```
<file name="External\COMCTL32.OCX">
    <typelib tlbid="{6B7E6392-850A-101B-AFC0-4210102A8DA7}" version="1.3" flags="control,hasdiskimage" helpdir="" />
    <comClass clsid="{9ED94440-E5E8-101B-B9B5-444553540000}" tlbid="{6B7E6392-850A-101B-AFC0-4210102A8DA7}" progid="COMCTL.TabStrip.1" threadingModel="Apartment" miscStatus="" miscStatusContent="recomposeonresize,cantlinkinside,insideout,activatewhenvisible,setclientsitefirst">
        <progid>COMCTL.TabStrip</progid>
    </comClass>
    ....
</file>
```

Notice that `miscStatus` has to be explicitly cleared.

We are using [UMMM](https://github.com/wqweto/UMMM) for manifest creation in our automated builds.